# How to add attachment to JIRA issue from web url using python?

Tags: python, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I've successfully attached a file to a existing issue via JIRA rest api using python :

```
    from jira.client import JIRA

    jira = JIRA(basic_auth=([username], [password]), options={'server': [our_jira_server]})

    issue = jira.issue([issue_id])

    file = open('test.txt')

    attachment_object = jira.add_attachment(issue,file)
```

But instead of local filepath , I need the file to be fetched from remote url. (Let's say google drive)
I 've read the [this](http://pythonhosted.org/jira/) document , but no help. If python implementation is there, its awesome ..But curl implementation would do good too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before adding attachment to Jira, just download the file to your script location and use it the same way as you have in your code sample

Comment: Thats what i'm trying now .. thanks